# find ratio of two sum amount of different type of transaction

Tags: sql, oracle

below code gives me following result

```
ACCOUNT_KEY EXECUTION_LOCAL_DATE_TIME   ACCT_CURR_AMOUNT    EXECUTION_LOCAL_DATE_TIME_1 ACCT_CURR_AMOUNT_1  SUM_AMOUNT  GROUP_TRANSACTION_TYPE_CD
49EBE0BE    00:00.0 100000  00:00.0 100000  200000  ALL-OUT
49EBE0BE    00:00.0 100000  00:00.0 50000   150000  ALL-INN
```

---

```
SELECT  T1.ACCOUNT_KEY, T1.EXECUTION_LOCAL_DATE_TIME,  
                         T1.ACCT_CURR_AMOUNT,T2.EXECUTION_LOCAL_DATE_TIME,T2.ACCT_CURR_AMOUNT,(T1.ACCT_CURR_AMOUNT + T2.ACCT_CURR_AMOUNT) AS SUM_AMOUNT,TG.Group_Transaction_Type_CD

   FROM CDS_SCHEMA_2.V_TRANSACTIONS T1 
         JOIN CDS_SCHEMA_2.V_TRANSACTIONS T2
            ON T1.ACCOUNT_KEY = T2.ACCOUNT_KEY
        JOIN CDS_SCHEMA_2.SAM_TRANS_CODE_TYPE_RELATION TC
            ON T2.TRANSACTION_CODE_CD = TC.TRANSACTION_CODE_CD
        JOIN CDS_SCHEMA_2.SAM_TRANS_TYPE_GROUP_RELATION TG
            ON  TG.TRANSACTION_TYPE_CD=TC.TRANSACTION_TYPE_CD
   WHERE  T1.execution_local_date_time between to_date('20170807', 'YYYYMMDD') and to_date('20170808', 'YYYYMMDD')
   AND    T2.execution_local_date_time between to_date('20170807', 'YYYYMMDD') and to_date('20170808', 'YYYYMMDD')
   AND    TRUNC(T2.EXECUTION_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) = TRUNC(T1.EXECUTION_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) + 1 
   AND T1.account_key = '49EBE0BE71C97B385960D17C8A85AE0B7B64382F'                                                      
   AND TG.Group_Transaction_Type_CD IN ('ALL-INN','ALL-OUT')
```

I need to find the ratio between SUM_AMOUNT for ALL-INN and SUM_AMOUNT for ALL-OUT (i.e SUM_AMOUNT for ALL-INN/SUM_AMOUNT for ALL-OUT) with the above query as subquery or join

Comment: Provide sample data and the output you want to get. This will help you get the answer much faster.

Comment: You've commented out some columns from your query. Why is that? If they aren't relevant to your question why include them? And if they are relevant why are they commented out? The harder you make it for us to understand your problem the longer it will take for you to get a helpful answer.

Comment: I made the changes to the script